# How do I test the call on a Vuex Mutation in a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

Say you have a vue component with a method like this:

```
methods:{
    doSomething(someParameter){
       //maybe do something with that Parameter 
       this.$store.commit("storeSomething",someParameter);

       let someParameter2 = this.transformToSth(someParameter);
       this.$store.commit("storeSomethingElse",someParameter2);
    }
}
```

What do I have to do, so that this kind of test works in Jest?

```
test("that the commit was correctly called",()=>{
     wrapper.vm.doSomething(someParameter);
     expect(wrapper.vm.$store.commit).hasBeenCalledWith(someParameter);

     expect(wrapper.vm.$store.commit).hasBeenCalledWith(someParameter2);
})
```

Also note that I want that the mock is also reverted again, so that method uses the same implementation as before. Otherwise, I create a dependency between tests, which I very much like to avoid.

(I also do hope it works the same way with actions and getter Functions)

Comment: Relevant documentation link: [Using Vue Test Utils with Vuex](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html#using-with-vuex)

Comment: @zcoop98 Yeah I have seen this. However, the scenario is slightly different. The Documentation wants to test an action more or less directly. I want to mock that action as I use it in a method in a component. But maybe I overlooked something...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found that one can solve this with spyOn:

```
   test("that the commit was correctly called", () => {
        let spy = jest.spyOn(userCardEditingWrapper.vm.$store, "commit");
        wrapper.vm.doSomething("test");
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("storeSomething", someParameter);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("storeSomethingElse", someParameter2);
      });
```

Credit to @devTea from the Vue Discord Channel that gave me the hint with jest.fn().